# Works properly, but not when running as administrator

Tags: batch-file, exe

My batch file makes another batch file. It works when you run it normally.

```
@echo off
type NUL > batchfile.bat
ECHO @echo off >> batchfile.bat
ECHO set hostspath=%%windir%%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts >> batchfile.bat
ECHO exit >> batchfile.bat
exit
```

However, when you run it as an administrator, it doesnt work. I need to make it run properly also when running as administrator. What is the correct way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

When you run as administrator, it changes the current context directory. I'm not sure *where* it changes to, but you can avoid that problem by specifying the full output path to the new batch file, like so:

```
@echo off
type NUL > "C:\Users\Troy\Documents\Software\batch files\batchfile.bat"
ECHO @echo off >> "C:\Users\Troy\Documents\Software\batch files\batchfile.bat"
ECHO set hostspath=%%windir%%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts >> "C:\Users\Troy\Documents\Software\batch files\batchfile.bat"
ECHO exit >> "C:\Users\Troy\Documents\Software\batch files\batchfile.bat"
exit
```

UPDATE: I just discovered that there's a way to dynamically change the current directory to the same one as the currently executing batch file. So, the following is probably a cleaner solution. It just involves adding one line at the top of the original script:

```
cd %~dp0
@echo off
type NUL > batchfile.bat
ECHO @echo off >> batchfile.bat
ECHO set hostspath=%%windir%%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts >> batchfile.bat
ECHO exit >> batchfile.bat
exit
```

Comment: Ah, it changes the current directory to _C:\Windows\System32_. I should've figured that.